# Node movement lag in Spritekit, Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit

In my game I have a node that the player controls with the `PanGesture`. When the `PanGesture` function is called, it adds its velocity to that of the Node in question, making it move.

However, I have encountered a problem where the Node (under specific yet inconsistent circumstances) moves slower and not as smoothly as intended.

When I start the application it (sometimes) has the correct movement speed. As soon as I "die", and restart (remove all nodes and recognizers, restart the scene, remake all nodes and recognizers) the node does not move at the correct speed.

This is where things get weird.

After restarting the game and seeing that the node has the incorrect speed, I can access the "swipe up menu" and then promptly dismiss it, at which point the node will revert back to its intended speed. This however, does not always work. On top of that, I can leave the scene to have the same thing happen. This happens even less frequently.

This is the code I use to make a `GestureRecognizer`:

```
let Panned:UIPanGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(GameScene.Panned))
view.addGestureRecognizer(Panned)
```

**These lines are only run once per scene.** (Making multiple GestureRecognizers causes the entire scene to experience dramatic frame drops each time the screen is touched.)

This is the code which adds the velocity of the movement to the Node:

```
func Panned(sender:UIPanGestureRecognizer){

    velocity = sender.velocity(in: view)

    if movement == true{

        Node.position.x = Node.position.x+(velocity.x/100)/1
        Node.position.y = Node.position.y-(velocity.y/100)/1

    }
}
```

This function is called each time the `PanGestureRecognizer` detects a "pan" movement.

This is my restart function, which prepares the scene for the next instance of the game:

```
func restartScene(){

    removeAllChildren()
    removeAllActions()

    createScene()

}
```

`removeAllChildren` will kill my stuttering node, and `createScene()` will revive it again. (It should be noted that `createScene()` is the same function used at the initial start of the game, and can therefor not be related to the problem.)

The restart is however where my problem starts. This function is missing certain (in my opinion) irrelevant lines that manipulate certain values and handle labels.

The main gist of my problem is as follows:

1. Do I fully understand `GestureRecognizers`?
2. What effect does the "swipe up menu" have on my current scene? Does it clear/restart certain things, or does it simply pause my scene?

Edit:

The most confusing thing about the problem is how it arises after a "restart", when the restart process does not touch the PanGesture in anyway. I'm considering remaking the game to create a version where the problem isn't present, but this leaves the problem unsolved.

Comment: It looks like the cause of your issue is potentially very subtle. Without seeing all of your code, it is hard to debug for you. I would recommend setting up a variety of breakpoints or print statements to further narrow down the source of the problem. As for the "swipe up menu", it's impossible to say what effect it has without knowing more about its implementation.

Comment: The most confusing part is this: The problem arises after a "restart", but the restart process doesn't touch the PanGesture in any way.

Comment: In custom classes ( subclasses of SKScene or SKSpriteNode etc) , override deinits. In Instruments check for leaks. Remove offscreen nodes (if not needed). Remove recognizers when about to transition between scenes and dont add them when a same scene is loaded if you havent removed them previously, because recognizers are part of a view (which presents scenes), and they not a part of a scene.

Comment: So when you cover all these fundamentals, if you are having the same result, you can try with profiling using instruments, or simply remove parts of a code in order to localize what causing the lag. Also you can tell the Xcode to analyize your project (product-> anayize I think)