# UIGesture thread not responding correctly

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

This question is a follow-up on my previous one: [Node movement lag in Spritekit, Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41325311/node-movement-lag-in-spritekit-xcode)

**TLDR:** (

*A Node in my game, which derives movement from `sender:UIPanGestureRecognizer)` will under certain very specific circumstances move much more slowly than intended. The strange thing is that it's original speed can temporarily be restored by using the swipe-up-menu. As soon as I initiate a restart of my game, the lagging continues.* )

**The problem:**

Essentially I've discovered that the `sender:UIPanGestureRecognizer)` function does not correctly update under certain circumstances. When my character Node is lagging, the `sender:UIPanGestureRecognizer)` updates at half the speed of `override func update(_ currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {` (which updates once per frame).

When I temporarily fix the problem by accessing the swipe-up-menu, the `sender:UIPanGestureRecognizer)` will update at the normal speed (Equal to `override func update(_ currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {`)

**Essentially:**

The `sender:UIPanGestureRecognizer)` thread is not running correctly.

Using an overlay feature (swipe-up, swipe-down) while my app is running "resets" the recognizer somehow. (However, going to the home-screen does not)

Switching scenes In-Game will sometimes "reset" the thread.

**My question:**

Does anybody know how / why this Gesture thread does not update correctly?